# Sorting NHibernate query results

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, sorting

```
public IEnumerable GetActive() 
{
   return Session.CreateQuery("from Agency where active=true order by agencyname").List();
}
```

Obviously, I can sort in the query itself, but what about doing it afterwards? I just want to sort the IEnumerable returned here. I can use the result in a foreach loop just fine, but I don't have the features available on a standard list collection (such as using LINQ to sort the data). What's the best method of sorting this?

Edit: this worked, and preserved the ability to use foreach:

```
public IEnumerable<Agency> GetActive() 
{
   return Session.CreateQuery("from Agency where active=true order by agencyname").List<Agency>();
}

foreach (Agency agency in agencies.OrderBy(c=>c.AgencyId)) { ... }
```

Comment: I actually tried that a few minutes ago, "source is not IEnumerable<>"

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: Version on NHibernate.dll is 3.0.0.4000.

Comment: My code was wrong. See mBotros's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to return a strongly typed list of the entity mapped to this Table

```
public IEnumerable<Agency> GetActive() 
{
   return Session.CreateQuery("from Agency where active=true")
   .List<Agency>().orderby(c=>c.agencyname);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before asking, but I get an error: "Interface 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not have type parameters"

Comment: return Session.CreateQuery("from Agency where active=true order by agencyname").List<Agency>(); then: foreach (Agency agency in agencies.OrderBy(c=>c.AgencyId)) { worked

Comment: Ah, the reason it didn't show up before was because I was not importing System.Collections.Generic, just System.Collections. Usually, resharper picks this kind of thing up.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the IENumerable to a LIst with the ToList() method, then sort.